# Check for zipcode , latitud, longitud range - using TKCustomMap-Xamarin-Forms

Tags: c#, google-maps, xamarin.forms, reverse-geocoding, compass-geolocation

I have a map that returns current address and location also geo coordinates. However, I would like to add a condition as follows : 
if address.zipcode is ( 05001 ||05009||05030 ) do something , if not display an alert . 
Zip Codes for the State of Vermont

Zip Code    City    Zip Code Map
05001   White River Junction
05009   White River Junction
05030

The problem I am facing is , it returned  the full address as a string. 
Is there any way I could validate only using the zipcode? 
so far , I tried 
`if (address.title .contains("05001")); {do this...} else{alert..}`
 Unfortunately , this wont work because those numbers can represent other things as a house number , city name , state or  country etc.
but the condition  does not  guarantee that it is in the states.

Thanks in advance !

Comment: It would be awesome if you could share a [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately the reverse geolocalization it returns a `List<string>` which cannot provide the field to access the specific information.
You can anyway do a dirty job reading the zip code splitting the string and getting the fourth element. (the zip code should be in this position, but you should double check)
Something like that:

```
var geo = new Geocoder ();
string []x;

var addresses = await geo.GetAddressesForPositionAsync (new Position (12.34516, -12.345678));
x = addresses.FirstOrDefault ().Split (',');

if(x[3].Contains("your zip code"))
    DisplayAlert("Alert");
```

It's not that elegant/robust but should do the job

Comment: test that with other positions, maybe the postal code could be in other positions (Y)